# How to select input box on google webpage for simple selenium test?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have created the following simple selenium test in order to start a browser, navigate to the `google` main page and to insert some text in the search box:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('do a test search' + Keys.RETURN)
```

However, I get the following error in the `send_keys` line:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not visible
```

Maybe this is a bad way to select the prominent input box on the google page? How to do it better?

(Remark: This is just supposed to be a simple setup to get selenium going. The system under test will be a different webpage, but I just want to make sure it works in this simple case...)

Comment: You should probably spend some time reading several Selenium tutorials. They will cover the various ways to locate elements and how to locate elements properly. Locating an element by just the tag name is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of hidden `input` elements located before search input field.

`browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input')` means *return FIRST "input" node in DOM*. That's why your `elem` is actually hidden node and not interactable.

Try below instead

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
```

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be not that easy as that. And with your suggestion it works as it should be. Thanks.